# Facebook login fail with Android App

Tags: android, facebook, session

I am Using Facebook login for user registration in android app.It works for me but some times
after clicking login button login window not open and screen hangup.
As i guess this issue because of session time out,when app try to connect with Facebook but if Facebook not respond then this cause occur.So how can i solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Edited:- Code is -

```
private void initFacebook(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
      uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      mSessionTracker = new SessionTracker(this, callback);
      mSessionTracker.startTracking();
}
```

and call back method which will call when user click on login button are-

```
private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
           if(state!= null){
                if(state.isOpened()){
                    mSession = session;
                    if(mLoginButton != null)
                     mLoginButton.setText(getString(R.string.loginwithfacebook));
                    showLoadingView();
                }
            }

        }
 };


 private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (pendingAction != PendingAction.NONE && (exception instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException ||
                exception instanceof FacebookAuthorizationException)) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(BaseActivity.this)
                    .setTitle(R.string.cancelled)
                    .setMessage(R.string.permission_not_granted)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null)
                    .show();
            pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;
        } else if (state == SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED) {
           handlePendingAction();
        }
    }
```

but the call back method not called some times.

Comment: Post some code and error log ravi

Answer (score 0):

retry until it success, or tomorrow.
facebook API was gone partially, it seems recovering...
https://www.facebook.com/developers/chart.php?type=at_error_count

Comment: Sir thanks for your reply,but i got this problem from last few days not from yesterday.So there may be some other issue.